# How to get the current revision number into a file after export?

Tags: svn, version-control, chui

I'm maintaining a homebrew web-based CRM that I version-control with Subversion. What I want is to have the revision number written into a file after I do an export to the production server so that I can display it in the CRM's status page for debugging reasons.

Is there any way to do this with command-line tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can't be sure after doing the export, because another commit might have happened just in-between. Practically, you can get the information with `svn info <URL>`. You could of course do the `svn info` first, extract the revision and export that revision to make sure both correspond.

If you do a checkout instead of an export, the information is available through `svn info <path>`.

Another way to do that is to use keywords in one of your exported file (let's call it script.h), like this:

```
#define VERSION_STRING  "r$Revision$"
// ... rest of the file
```

If you give the svn:keywords property to your file (and commit it), the $Revision$ will be substituted at checkout or export:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Revision" script.h
```

(there are other substitutions, check the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) for further details)

Comment: If you use the `Revision` keyword, then it will be replaced at checkout/export by the revision number this file was changed last. Not exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) to always have the information present in a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ant as your build tool, you can write a [custom Ant task](http://workingonit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/addenda/src/java/org/workingonit/addenda/subversion/SubversionInfoTask.java) to grab the information from a remove Subversion server, store them into the Ant project's properties and use substitution to place these values into some properties/class.

Since you're certainly building you production application from a Subversion tags, you will not have the risk to display a wrong information (like RegGlyph mentioned)