# Nightly build for VB.NET program, Versioning

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, nightly-build

I currently have a nightly build system running as a windows scheduled task, calling at batch file, that works sort of like this:

- Check out the latest revision from subversion
- Modify the AssemblyInfo.vb file of the main executable and the librarys to set the version number to 0.0.0.revision
- Invoke MSBuild to build everything (including the installer)
- Upload the installer and a log of the build to an FTP server

This works ok, but step 2 is dirty and fragile, and I can't imagine that this the only way to do what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to deal with this. You may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621663/) or others tagged with svn (and containing "AssemblyInfo").

Comment: thanks, the Community Tasks stuff was helpful. Shame they arn't being developed any more